Monaco-editor. Как подсвечивать в css числа после ":" (1, 1px, 1rem, 1.2em, и т.п)
У меня есть такой код:
 monaco.editor.defineTheme('customTheme', {
                base: 'vs-dark',
                inherit: true,
                rules: [
                    { token: 'comment', foreground: window.commentColor},
                    { token: 'keyword', foreground: window.keywordColor },
                    { token: 'string', foreground: window.stringColor },
                    { token: 'variable', foreground: window.variableColor },
                    { token: 'number', foreground: window.numberColor },
                    { token: 'delimiter', foreground: window.delimiterColor },
                    { token: 'tag', foreground: window.tagColor },
                    { token: 'attribute', foreground: window.attributeColor },
                    { token: 'attribute.value', foreground: window.attributeValueColor },
                    { token: 'namespace', foreground: window.namespaceColor },
                    { token: 'type', foreground: window.typeColor },
                    { token: 'attribute.name', foreground: window.attributeNameColor },                    
                ],  

И мне нужно добавить токен для чисел после ":" в css
пример:
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

вот эти числа (0,0,0,0.1 ; 0 0 10px ; 20px ; 80%;)
они по дефолту подсвечиваются #b5cea8 а я хочу другой цвет, но я не знаю токен для этих чисел(мне вообще кажется что его нет)
